# How to reverse the byte order of a 4 byte constant in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am wondering on how to reverse the byte order on a 4 byte constant string (e.g 0x243F6A88->0x88 0x3F 0x6A 0x88). My current solution will do this: 0x243F6A88->886A3F240x. Here is the code I have so far:

```
value = "0x243F6A99"
joined = "".join(map(str.__add__, value[-2::-2] ,value[-1::-2]))
print(joined)
```

Any insight appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the string has exactly eight hex digits, then

```
value = "0x243F6A99"
joined = "0x" + "".join(map(str.__add__, value[-2:1:-2] ,value[-1:2:-2]))
print(joined)
```

should be enough.

Comment: You could also replace `str.__add__` with `"{}{}".format` to the same effect.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace Because of the `map` the `"{}{}".format` would have to be wrapped in a `lambda` so it would be neither more readable nor more efficient than `str.__add__`.

Comment: I don't think `lambda` is needed. Any of `str.__add__`, `"{}{}".format` or `operator.add` are reasonable imo.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace Oh, right, `lambda` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

for Python2:

```
value="243F6A99".decode('hex')
value=value[::-1]
print (value.encode('hex'))
```

for Python3:

```
value=bytes.fromhex("243F6A99")
value=value[::-1]
print(bytes.hex(value))
```

Comment: yes. just checked python2 string.decode/encode has moved to bytes.fromhex/hex in python3. thx for prompt.

Comment: Thanks! This is a viable solution but it didn't work in my situation since the string constants I am trying to convert are not treated as hex for some reason (I'm using pycparser to parse and convert constants in C code)